# Problemas Arduino GSM/GPS

Tags: arduino, gps

Buenas Colegas, tengo un proyecto donde envio mis coordenadas a una base de datos en Mysql, utilizo el SIM808, el cual trae para GPS/GSM. La idea es estar mando coordenadas al server por medio del metodo GET

El problema que tengo esque llamo la siguiente función en el loop

```
  void enviarDatos(){
  String id = "456789";

   Serial.println(lat+" "+lon+" "+id);

   myGsm.println("AT+HTTPPARA=URL,http://miServer/getArduino.php?latitud="+lat+"&longitud="+lon+"&dispositivo="+id);
   delay(1000);
   printSerialData();

   myGsm.println("AT+HTTPACTION=0");
   delay(500);
   printSerialData();

   }
```

Al realizar este proceso en el Loop, este deberia de repetirse hasta el final de los dias, pero lo que pasa es que aveces solo me envia latitud, o longitud, e incluso aveces me da las coordenadas incompletas, y si lo dejamos mas tiempo se empiezan como a combinar todas las instrucciones, al punto que ni siquiera envia los datos

Queria saber si alguno tiene alguna clase de sugerencia, no se si tendre que realizar algun tipo de FLush cada cierto tiempo, porque pareciera que mezcla datos anteriores con los nuevos.

Gracias por cuaquier aporte, Saludos

Comment: Hola Andrey Buenos Días , coincidencialmente estoy trabajando tambien con un Arduino UNO y un modulo GSM SIM 808, me gustaría saber como hiciste para extraer las variables latitud, longitud,altura , velocidad y resto de variables que muestra el módulo al ejecutar el comando AT+CGPSINF=0... Quedo Atento a tu respuesta Saludos...

Comment: Hola Santiago, utilice una funcion como esta:
Lo que hace unicamente es recorrer el While hasta toparse con una ","
y los vamos concatenando, para luego almacenarlos en un array 

      while(myGsm.available()){       
        char c = myGsm.read();
          if(c != ','){ //leer datos hasta enconrar , 
          latlongtab[i]+=c;
           delay(20);
        }else{
          i++;        
       }
      if(i == 5){
          delay(20);
          goto exitL;
        }       
      }    
    }exitL:


Saludos desde centro America,

Comment: si vas a estar mandando las coordenadas, utiliza un POST en lugar de un GET. :)